# Keeping one item in a list that should be disabled

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, where-clause

I have a page that contains a list a companies. Each company is appart of a group, like such:

[image]

But here's the catch, groups can be disabled, if they are, that would not change the display of the list but it does have an impact on my edition page.

[image]

As you can see, there is a `DropDownList` containing my groups. But if a group is **disabled** it does not show up on the list because I retrieve said list like such:

```
 public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ListGroupEnabled()
 {
     List<SelectListItem> X = _entities.Groups.Where(p => p.IsEnabled).ToList().Select(c => new SelectListItem { Value = c.GroupId.ToString(), Text = c.Name }).ToList();
     return X;
 }
```

But here's what I wish to achieve:

If I were to edit a company that was appart of a disabled group, I still want that group (and **only** that group) to appear in the DDList among enabled groups.

This is for the sake of logic, it wouldn't make sense to simply not have the group a company is appart off in its list.

How may I change the code I showed up above in order to keep the group the company is appart off in my list?

Answer (score 0):

Hello SelectListItem have Properties such as Disabled you can set it before send. [referrence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlistitem(v=vs.118).aspx)

fix your code at below.

```
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ListGroupEnabled()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> X = _entities.Groups.Select(c => new SelectListItem { Value = c.GroupId.ToString(), Text = c.Name , Disabled = c.IsEnabled }).ToList();
        return X;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in the current group id and include that in your where clause:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ListGroupEnabled(int? currentGroupId = null)
{
    return _entities.Groups.Where(
        p =>
            p.IsEnabled ||
            (currentGroupId.HasValue && p.GroupId == currentGroupId.Value)
    ).Select(c => new SelectListItem { Value = c.GroupId.ToString(), Text = c.Name }).ToList();
}
```

You also don't need to call `ToList` before selecting. That actually makes the query less optimized as without that, Entity Framework can just select the columns it needs (`GroupId` and `Name`).